# How to create msi file or exe file from ism file using installshield

Tags: installation, installshield

I have a ism file and want to create setup file (msi or exe) using installshield. I am new to install shield so if anybody can explain step by step then it would be help full.

Comment: This resource will help you to [Get started with InstallShield](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/helplibrary/IHelpGetStart.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Just open .ism file in installshield and click on build button. After that click on folder icon to open your exe or msi.

i.e. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVQZ2.png

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Media > Releases.  Listed release configurations are the possible configurations for your build.  You can right-click and build the preferred one (if multiple exist). Compression, logging , local cache, languages, data extraction is all controlled through this configuration.